# MySQL CREATE FUNCTION result with multiple records gives error #1172

Tags: mysql, function, user-defined-functions

I have the following 3 tables:

```
table "name"       
---------------
id     name
---------------
1      book
2      pen


table "color"
------------------
id     color
------------------
1       red
2       yello
3       green
4       pink


table "both"
------------------------
id     name      color
----------------------
1      1            1
2      1            2
3      1            3
4      2            2
```

and I have the following function:

```
    DELIMITER //

    CREATE FUNCTION get_word(n VARCHAR(20))
        RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
        READS SQL DATA
        DETERMINISTIC
        BEGIN
            DECLARE b VARCHAR(20);
       SELECT  `color`.`color` INTO b  FROM   `name` 
        LEFT JOIN `both` 
          ON `name`.`id`=`both`.`name`
        LEFT JOIN `color`
          ON `color`.`id`=`both`.`color` 
       WHERE `name`.`name`=n;        

        RETURN b;
        END//

    DELIMITER ;
```

now when I run 
**SELECT get_word('pen')**
it returns **yellow** which is what is expect.

but when I run the code
**SELECT get_word('book')**
it get error: #1172 - Result consisted of more than one row

**my Question:**
What to do so this function works with multiple records as well as single record which it does when I search for "pen"?
thanks

**UPDATE:**

If use the query without the function as follow, it just works fine:

```
       SELECT  `color`.`color` AS b  FROM   `name` 
        LEFT JOIN `both` 
          ON `name`.`id`=`both`.`name`
        LEFT JOIN `color`
          ON `color`.`id`=`both`.`color` 
       WHERE `name`.`name`='book';
```

and it returns:

```
**b**
red
yellow
green
```

Comment: what's your desired result when you have multiple records ? 'book' has red, yellow and green as results. So what should be returned ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus - I would like to get all the color

Comment: Yes, but how  ? A "list", a concatenated string ?

Comment: I should show a column with multiple records.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus - I updated the question at the bottom.

Comment: does it have to do anything with the RETURNS VARCHAR(10)? can we change the return type to be multiple row?

Comment: Well, in fact no, you can't do this in a function. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it seems that you want a resultset (more than one value)

But a mysql stored function cannot return a resultset (see [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html) : Restrictions for Stored Functions).

**Solution 1** : use a stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_word(n VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
 SELECT  `color`.`color` 
 FROM   `name` 
   LEFT JOIN `both` 
          ON `name`.`id`=`both`.`name`
   LEFT JOIN `color`
          ON `color`.`id`=`both`.`color` 
   WHERE `name`.`name`=n; 
END
```

**Solution2** : return a concatenated string

something like `"green, yellow, blue"` 
GROUP_CONCAT can do that easily.
see this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field) for example

Comment: Thank you. It worked perfectly. What is the difference and limitation of PROCEDURE with FUNCTION?

Comment: Well, one big limitation on procedure is that you can't use it in a query... For more details and info, see for example this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744209/mysql-stored-procedure-vs-function-which-would-i-use-when

Answer (score 0):

Try to use group by after `where` , for example try to add `group by id` or something what is unique in your table.

Comment: didn't get what you say. Nothing is unique in "both" table. A book can have "red", "yellow" and Green.