# Display size column as row for each color product in related table?

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a query to read and combine three tables. Below, a simplified design of the database tables:

```
Table: Sizes             Table: Colors
+------+------+         +------+-------+
| id   | size |         | id   | color | 
+------+------+         +------+-------+
|    1 |   32 |         |    1 | red   |
|    2 |   34 |         |    2 | blue  |
|    3 |   36 |         |    3 | green |
|    4 |   38 |         |    4 | white |
+------+------+         +------+-------+
```

```
Table: Orders 
+------+------+-------+--------+
| id   | size | color | amount |
+------+------+-------+--------+
|    1 |    1 |     1 |      1 |
|    2 |    1 |     2 |      3 |
|    3 |    2 |     2 |      4 |
|    4 |    3 |     2 |      2 |
+------+------+-------+--------+
```

So, the query should return always all the sizes and return just the colors if there is actually a product in that color. So, with the product table above described, i would a query which is return the following data:

```
+-------+------+------+------+------+
|       | 32   | 34   | 36   | 38   |
+-------+------+------+------+------+
| red   |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| blue  |    3 |    4 |    2 |    0 |
+-------+------+------+------+------+
```

Of course, the query returns just the combination of the size, color and amount and a PHP script will generate the table of it. Could somebody help with it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your approach is correct. Nonetheless, this is very basic. What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried some querys with inner and outer joins, but the main problem is that the query is returning all the colors instead of just the colors from the orders table. Or, with an inner join, the query is just returning the order columns and not all the sizes.

Comment: looks like you have changed your question.. may I know why?

Comment: I've changed the question because of a table which was wrong. The table is named 'orders' but by posting the question I named it 'products'. Of course there is another table with the product information. I've simplified the table structure for the question.

Comment: I was trying to answer with products, now it looks it doesn't make sense to answer because you may change question even after posting my answer...

Comment: Sorry for it, could you try it again?

Comment: @Stefan I posted an answer with for your updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no PIVOT command (MySQL [pivot tables (transform rows to columns)](http://buysql.com/mysql/12-how-to-pivot-tables.html)) in MySQL so your query will be static for size. That is why it is better to postponed this in application.

Thought if you have just finite and small domain for size column then you can use following Query I posted below:

```
mysql> SELECT 
    ->      c.color as color,
    ->      SUM(IF(s.size = 32, o.amount, 0)) as '32',
    ->      SUM(IF(s.size = 34, o.amount, 0)) as '34',
    ->      SUM(IF(s.size = 36, o.amount, 0)) as '36',
    ->      SUM(IF(s.size = 38, o.amount, 0)) as '38'
    ->  FROM `colors` c
    ->  INNER JOIN `order` o
    ->  INNER JOIN `sizes` s
    ->      WHERE c.`id` = o.`color` and s.`id` = o.`size`
    -> GROUP BY color 
    -> ;
+-------+------+------+------+------+
| color | 32   | 34   | 36   | 38   |
+-------+------+------+------+------+
| blue  |    3 |    4 |    2 |    0 |
| red   |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
+-------+------+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

As you can see in IF conditions I use value of size that is what I means question is static. I am assuming all possible size can be either 32, 34, 36, 38.

Working demo @[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5e62/1)

Edit: As I am saying from starting If size values are unkown or domain is large then better is you postponed pivot work within your server script (e.g. PHP) still you can use following query to process in script:

```
SELECT 
     c.color as color,
     s.size,
     o.amount  --Edit: added 
 FROM `colors` c
 INNER JOIN `order` o
 INNER JOIN `sizes` s
     WHERE c.`id` = o.`color` and s.`id` = o.`size`
```

See how does it works @[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5e62/7).

Comment: Looks really great, but there is just one problem. The table sizes is provided with an unknown number of sizes. So, it isn't possible to name them all in the query I think?

Comment: @Stefan As I said there is no POvite command, Either you have to write [stored procedures and function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744209/mysql-stored-procedure-vs-function-which-would-i-use-when/13510102#13510102) or do this complete work in PHP code.

Comment: Thanks for your hulp Grijesh, I will write a PHP script for it! Thanks.

Comment: @Stefan Your welcome, would you mind to mark my answer as useful.

Comment: @Stefan  I further updated Query that would be easy to process in your script. -- By the ways "amount" should be actually "quantity"