# SQL - get all level data in recursive table into one row

Tags: sql, recursive-query

A Branch belongs to an Area

Table Branch

```
ID      Name   AreaID
-------------------
1   | Branch1 | 3
2   | Branch2 | 5
```

Table Area

```
ID    Name   AreaID
-------------------
1   | Area1 |   null
2   | Area2 |   1
3   | Area3 |   2
4   | Area4 |   3
5   | Area5 |   4
```

I want to join Branch and Area, and get all Area parents.
So, the expected result is:

```
BrachID BranchName AreaID AreaName AreaID1 AreaName1 AreaID2 AreaName2 AreaID3 AreaName3 AreaID4 AreaName4
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      | Branch1  | null | null   | null  | null    | 3     | Area3   | 2     | Area2   | 1     | Area1 
2      | Branch2  | 5    | Area5  | 4     | Area4   | 3     | Area3   | 2     | Area2   | 1     | Area1
```

Please teach me the sql (sql only) to get data like the expected result.

Thanks

Comment: check this [Display size column as row for each color product in related table?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23042616/1673391)

Comment: thanks! but, problem in your link is different. I searching Hierarchical Queries (connect by in oracle)

Comment: ask on this site : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30021/mysql-tree-hierarchical-query