# phpmyadmin run mysql stored procedure but no output

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I write a very simple stored procedure as below:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS GetAllTours;

DELIMITER // 

CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllTours() 

BEGIN 

SELECT * FROM tours; 

END // 

DELIMITER ;
```

When I use

```
CALL GetAllTours();
```

from SQL query to run this procedure, there is no output.

But if I run from `>>Routines>>Execute`, the same procedure, there will have output successfully.

Can anybody tell me how to run from SQL query and get the results?

Answer (score 3):

You can just use this query: 
CALL `GetAllTours`

Answer (score -2):

First of all, i think you are trying to create a view. Take a look here: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html

```
mysql> CREATE VIEW GetAllActiveTours AS SELECT * FROM tours where active=1;
mysql> select * from GetAllActiveTours;
```

for returning data from a procedure use an OUT parameter.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

example from link above:

```
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc (OUT param1 INT)
    -> BEGIN
    ->   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO param1 FROM t;
    -> END//
mysql> CALL simpleproc(@a);
mysql> SELECT @a;
```

Comment: This is a command-line test. The OP was about calling from phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Great style to give -1 more than a year later because you did not read the question properly... OP asked:  'Can anybody tell me how to run from SQL query and get the results?'

Comment: He meant SQL query, that's a tab in phpMyAdmin. I am struggling with the same problem.

Comment: The main problem here is that a procedure is probably not what you want to fix this. Procedures are not meant to return sets of filtered data. Most likely you will want a view or a function (should you want to return a single scalar). take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744209/mysql-stored-procedure-vs-function-which-would-i-use-when Perhaps i can take a better look at your problem over chat to prevent pollution of this topic.