# Calling MySQL stored procedure and Displaying its data in CAKEPHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I want to call my stored procedure which accept only one integer input parameter and return multiple rows in cakephp framework.

**Stored Procedure:**

```
PROCEDURE `Salary`(IN sysid int )
BEGIN
SELECT name, lastName, Salary, Month From SalaryData 
where Userid = sysid;
END
```

**Model.PHP:**

```
<?php
 class SalaryModel extends AppModel
 {
   public function sProcedure($testId) 
{
    $result=$this->query("CALL Salary($testId);");
    return $result;
}
 }?>
```

**My Controller code is:**

```
public function Procdata($testId) {
    $result=$this->Systemstate->sProcedure($testId);
 }
```

Now, Can anyone suggests me how to display the content of query in **"view.ctp"** ??

I hope my model is correct.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you trying to use a stored procedure? Why not just generate a query using the framework?

Comment: because its a complex query, including max functions etc and after everything it results is returned as a select query from stored procedure

Comment: @Nomanuddin please only tag questions with the relevant version of CakePHP you are using. Are you using CakePHP 1 or 2?

Comment: I am using 2, okay i will update, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various methods to call stored procedures in cakephp. but the best way is to execute it as a query instead of baking it as a model,
because up to my search there is no way to build or bake complex stored procedures.

So, this way I solved my issue:

**My Controller code is:**

```
    public function Procdata($testId) {
    $result=$this->Systemstate->sProcedure($testId);
    $this->set('data',$result);
 }
```

**My Display Section View.CTP**

```
   print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL stored procedure does not usually return some result.
You need to develop FUNCTION instead to return some value.
Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744209/mysql-stored-procedure-vs-function-which-would-i-use-when).

Comment: okay If I use a function, any suggestion how to call and display content in cakephp?