# Mysql how to use a local variable in an update

Tags: mysql

I have a query running on a large table, so I need it to run as optimized as possible, and would like to clean up this particular equation.

```
SET points = IF( 
    (20 - ABS(pick.guessed_rank - team.rank)) < 0,
    0,
    (20 - ABS(pick.guessed_rank - team.rank))
)
```

How can i improve this to save the `ABS(pick.guess_rank - team.rank)` to a variable so my update can look more something like:

```
@diff = ABS(pick.guess_rank - team.rank;
SET points = IF(@diff < 0, 0, @diff);
```

Or perhaps there is a better solution than using an if statement for this, but an example of how to use a variable in this situation would still be helpful.

Comment: You can do a simple function MYSQL and give too parameter guess_rank and rank and under the function you can ABS en return de result as @diff store in your example or do a UPDATE ON SELECT. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744209/mysql-stored-procedure-vs-function-which-would-i-use-when

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `GREATEST` function that does logically the same thing:

```
SET @points = GREATEST(20 - ABS(pick.guessed_rank - team.rank), 0);
```

or more specifically

```
SET @diff = 20 - ABS(pick.guessed_rank - team.rank);
SET @points = GREATEST(@diff,0);
```

and for extra bonus points

```
SET @min_margin=20;
SET @diff = ABS(pick.guessed_rank - team.rank);
SET @points_diff = GREATEST(@diff,@min_margin);
```

--- EDIT ---

In direct SQL CLI, I had to use `@` for every variable. I believe there is a difference in a `stored procedure`

Comment: Oh yah, that's what I'm talking about!

Comment: Actually I don't know if this is right. It's throwing an  error on the set @diff. Can you use this syntax to set a local variable in an update? I am using this set in an update `update pick SET set @diff = ... SET pick.points = ...` Should it still work?

Comment: I always get in trouble with the use of @ in variable and `SET`. Let me confirm and update the result. The `GREATEST` is still your ticket