# MySQL Stored procedure SELECT var wrong value after INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a problem on MySQL stored procedure, already did another logic with IF THEN ELSE, but I still have problems which I cant understand...

The procedure consists on two user inputs: **user_id** and **meet_id**. The procedure define a variable called **'ue'** which stores result of a bunch of validation (*if user exists, if event exists, if event date is still valid, etc.*).

After that, it does INSERT and UPDATE some data on multiple tables in IF THEN ELSE selector, and SELECT 1 (or 0) AS result depending of validation.

But my problem is: it always return me 0 as 'result', as if my validation variable was 0 when I do INSERT... And there is where things get weird, if I remove the INSERT [...]; line of the code, it returns me the value of validation correctly (1 or 0).

The code of the procedure is this one:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`nwouserf`@`localhost` 
PROCEDURE `join_event`(IN `user_id` BIGINT(64), IN `event_id` INT) 
NOT DETERMINISTIC MODIFIES SQL DATA SQL SECURITY DEFINER 

begin 
DECLARE ue INT; 
SET ue = EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE fb_uid=user_id) 
         AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM meetup WHERE meet_id=event_id) 
         AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM meetup WHERE date > NOW() AND meet_id = event_id) 
         AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM meetup WHERE meet_id = event_id AND participants <= max_participants) 
         AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM meetup_participation WHERE fb_uid = user_id AND meet_id = event_id); 

IF ue = 1 THEN 

    INSERT INTO meetup_participation (fb_uid, meet_id) VALUES (user_id, event_id); 
    UPDATE users SET events_participated = events_participated + 1 WHERE fb_uid=user_id; 
    UPDATE meetup SET participants = participants + 1 WHERE meet_id=event_id; 
    SELECT 1 AS result; 

ELSEIF ue = 0 THEN 
    SELECT 0 AS result; 
ELSE 
    SELECT null AS result; 
END IF; 
end
```

Thanks in advance! 
I have been stuck on this for a while now, and can not figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

You should define OUT parameter. Add

", OUT result INT"

immediately after the last IN parameter.

Comment: Still not the right solution I think, as it works without OUT parameter and INSERT parameter... But I did a work-around with your answer as I did on the other procedures I have created... Had to change SELECT to SET, and do a double query. The only problem it is on PHP, it is not a good idea to multi-query in my opinion, as I have to CALL procedure and select output variable, it may fail on a query and continue to the next one.

Comment: And why you dont't create this as a function then? It looks much better from what I am hearing from you.

Comment: I am new to MySQL, I might be wrong, but from what I have read so far, functions should not be used when you do modify data on tables (INSERT, UPDATE are not allowed). [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1179778/2612722)

Comment: Both are routines. Where did you read that, sounds wrong to me? Take a look at this link to read more about the [difference between procedure and function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680745/differences-between-procedure-and-function-and-routine) as well.

Comment: You are right, the link I gave on the end is SQL Server, not MySQL... Reading on MySQL documentation I wasn't able to find anything related, so I tested it and it worked out, thanks!